# Doing two things simultaneously

Tags: sentence-construction

> I'm reading a book.

And at the same time:

> I'm listening to music.

Combining these, we have:

> I'm reading a book while listening to music.

Am I correct?

What are the other ways to express this?

I'm talking only about **present continuous tense.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All of these are possible:

> I'm reading a book at the same time as listening to music.
>
> At the same time as reading a book, I'm listening to music.
>
> I'm reading a book and listening to music at the same time.
>
> I'm  at the same time reading a book and listening to music.
>
> I'm simultaneously reading a book and listening to music.
>
> I'm reading a book and listening to music simultaneously.
>
> Simultaneously, I'm reading a book and listening to music.

Comment: Or just simply *I'm reading a book and listening to music.*